# How to use Environnement in <filter> domain

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Using Odoo 10 (fetched from GitHub commit [7413b26](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/7413b2624c6554bf641c2426c45c70fd59bc7490), branch `10.0`), I try to use the environnement in a search filter domain applied to a tree view. Like this:

```xml
<filter string="Metal" domain="[('attribute_id','=', self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('my_module.attrib_metal', None))]" help="metal"/>
```

But Odoo won't let me use `self`:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

---

I also tried to filter my ­­­`attrib_metal` with Python by saving the result in a field but I don't want to store it in my database, however Odoo search requires it to be.

In my Python:

```py
def get_my_params(self):
    attrid = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param(
            'my_module.attrib_metal', None)
    if attrid:
        for rec in self:
            setattr(rec, attrib_metal, rec.attribute_id.id == int(attrid))

attrib_metal = fields.Boolean(store=False, compute="get_cr_params")
```

This code is part of an inhereted `product.attribute.value` model.

In my XML view:

```xml
<filter string="Metal" domain="[('attrib_metal', '=', 'True')]" help="metal"/>
```

I have tried with the `store = True` parameter, but this way the value is stored in the database and is only computed **once**, which is not what I'm looking for.

So this is not the right way of doing it.

---

How can one use the environnement in a `<filter>` domain?

Comment: `store=False` means that odoo won't store that field in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is being evaluated in the web client (frontend/Javascript). The web client knows nothing about `self`. Also, the dot notation in the filters is not supported. **You will need to create a new field for this** as the domains are run on the javascript side and you cannot execute code there. The new field must also be **stored** in the database. This pattern is used all over Odoo.

use: 
`<field name="your_field" invisible="1" />` to bring it to your view and to keep it invisible and then

```
<filter string="Metal" domain="[('attribute_id','=', your_field]" help="metal"/>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify my request: I want to compute the field each time that is displayed. But `store=True` executes this just one time.

Comment: Then you have to decorate the method that computes the field with `api.depends('another_field')`. So every time the `another_field` changes, your field will be recomputed. If you want your field to be re-computed every time it is shown you have to override the `fields_get` base method and calculate the field there. IMHO that would not be a good idea.